# Prevent NSURLSessionDataTask from repeatedly firing request

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am using a NSURLSessionDataTask to get JSON data from a device that opens an adhoc-WiFi which is joined by an iPhone. (The connection is running via TCP).

The device is pretty slow - it takes roundabout 5sec to send the particular response.
After firing the request via `dataTask.resume()` my app is just waiting for the completionHandler to be called.
Unfortunately the **request is fired again and again** (each after a delay of ~ 1 sec). I guess this is initiated by the dataTask or NSURLSession. I can monitor the repeated requests when debugging the device.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "<myURL>")! 

let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPShouldUsePipelining = false
configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1
configuration.allowsCellularAccess = false
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(URL) {
// the request gets fired repeatedly before this completionHandler is called!
(data, response, error) -> Void in
...
}

dataTask.resume()
```

Does anyone know how to prevent iOS from re-firing these requests?

Comment: You'l have greater chances of getting answers if you paste your code here.

Comment: Are you using https? If so Implement the func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void)

Comment: No, I'm not using https - the device doesn't support that. I'm just accessing via http.